# Подсчитать сколько раз каждое слово встречается в тексте

Tags: python, массивы, строки, динамические-массивы, словари

Написал вот такой вот код(neps - массив строк текста):

```
`dict = {}
for i in range(len(neps)):
    slova = neps[i].split(" ")
    for w in range(len(slova)):
        if slova[w] in dict == False:
            dict[slova[w]] = 1
        else:
            dict[slova[w]] +=1`
```

Но компилятор выдает ошибку:

> line 61, in wiki function dict[slova[w]] +=1.

Подскажите как можно иначе увеличивать значение ключа на один.

Comment: Вместо ``if slova[w] in dict == False`` нужно использовать ``if slova[w] not in dict``. Ваш вариант делает совсем не то, что вы думаете.

Answer (score 4):

Можно проще

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

frequencies = Counter(chain.from_iterable(i.split() for i in neps))
```

И не стоит переопределять имена встроенных функций и типов.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {}
for i in range(len(neps)):
    slova = neps[i].split(" ")
    for w in range(len(slova)):
        if not slova[w] in dict:
            dict[slova[w]] = 1
        else:
            dict[slova[w]] += 1
```